# ASP.NET Core MVC form action Url does not redirect to controller/method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, form-submit

ASP.NET Core 2 MVC web app.

I have a page for updating data with this form action

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Update", "Client")" id="formUpdate" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

The Url of the application is

```
https://localhost:88/Home/Client
```

When I submit it should go to `Update` method in `Client` controller, but it redirect to

```
https://localhost:88/Update
```

I know I have to set this path in `Program.cs`. The path I have set is

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Menu}/{id?}");
```

and some other regarding Authentication and Logout.

How can I set the path for all `<form>` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Url.action will check the route is exists or not, if the route is not exists, it will not generate the right path, f you don't want this, you could directly useing the `/Client/Update`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the endpoint could not be found. I had

this attribute in the header of the method

```
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

When I remove that, it worked